# Refresh Token is empty and AllowOfflineAccess is true and scope I have offline_access

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

The Refresh Token is always empty, this is my code:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "mvc",
    ClientName = "MVC Client",
    RequireConsent = false,
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,

    ClientSecrets = {new Secret("secret".Sha256())},
    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:7002/Account/callback" }, //{ "http://localhost:7002/signin-oidc" }, //
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:7002/signout-callback-oidc" },

    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
    {

        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
        "api1"
    },
    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true
}
```

And this is my MVCClient

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
    .AddCookie("Cookies")
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

        options.Authority = "http://localhost:7000";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

        options.ClientId = "mvc";
        options.ClientSecret = "secret";
        options.ResponseType = "code id_token token";

        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

        options.Scope.Add("api1");
        options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
    });
```

I login by creating the authorize url, and this is how I create it:

```
var host = _context.HttpContext.Request.Host.Host; 
var discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient(Configuration["auth:oidc:authority"]);
var disco = await discoveryClient.GetAsync();
var request = new RequestUrl(disco.AuthorizeEndpoint);
authorizeUrl = request.CreateAuthorizeUrl(
    clientId: "mvc",
    responseType: "code id_token token",
    responseMode: OidcConstants.ResponseModes.FormPost,
    scope: "openid profile api1 offline_access",
    redirectUri: "http://localhost:7002/Account/callback", //"http://localhost:7002/signin-oidc", // 
    state: CryptoRandom.CreateUniqueId(),
    nonce: CryptoRandom.CreateUniqueId(),
    acrValues: host);

return Redirect(authorizeUrl);
```

I am redirected to the login page, I do the login, and once I logged in, and return to the CallBack() (in the HomeController) I get everything except an empty refresh_token:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Callback()
{
    var code = Request.Form["code"];
    var tokenType = Request.Form["token_type"];
    var idToken = Request.Form["id_token"];
    var scope = Request.Form["scope"];
    var state = Request.Form["state"];
    var session_state = Request.Form["session_state"];
    var error = Request.Form["error"];
    var expiresAt = Request.Form["expires_in"];
    var accessToken = Request.Form["access_token"];
    var refreshToken = Request.Form["refresh_token"];
}
```

To Recap: refresh_token is empty {}, not null. To test it in other way, to the about method I added the [authorize], and if I login by clicking only there, then I do have a refresh_token.

Am I missing something?

Comment: why are you creating the authorization URL yourself?

Comment: @DalmTo because the nature of the website that I am creating needs it this way, I cannot show others views/pages until the user is logged in.

Comment: [authorize] at the top of all your controllers would force it to redirect to login.    Why exactly are you doing it manually?

Comment: @DalmTo I am sending in acrValues: host (subdomain), because this application will be use by different customer using the Same Client MVC, but every customer has its own subdomain. If I don't send the sub-domain to the authentication server, I won't know which database to search, and this is the only way that I found it to do it.
 Please, feel free to advice me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can only get a refresh token via a token endpoint call. You need to call `/connect/token` using the `code` you get back in the callback.

Also, since you're doing the request and callback manually there's probably no point in calling `AddOpenIdConnect`.

Comment: I will try to implement your advice with the /connect/token, and the addOpenIdConnect I still need it because I need to insert it to the services, otherwise I will get an error.

Comment: This is the need that I have, and I explained to @DalmTo, please feel free to advice as well. Thanks
""I am sending in acrValues: host (subdomain), because this application will be use by different customer using the Same Client MVC, but every customer has its own subdomain. If I don't send the sub-domain to the authentication server, I won't know which database to search, and this is the only way that I found it to do it. Please, feel free to advice me. Thanks""